# iptables: Logging connections on port 25/TCP

Tags: iptables, logs, kvm, smtp

I have KVM virtualization. I have over 60 interfaces:

```
vnet1-60 - virtual;
vmbr0 - bridge;
enp2s0f0 - PHYSOUT;
```

I need to know how many connection make each vnet interface.
I have a rule like:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -o vnet1 -m state -p tcp --dport 25 --state NEW -j 
LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix "25port: "
```

... but no result. Same no result:

```
-A OUTPUT -o vnet*;
-A OUTPUT -o vnet55,vnet56; 
-A OUTPUT -o enp2s0f0;
```

I get logs only when I use this:

```
-A FORWARD -o vmbr0 -s 123.0.0.0/8 -m state -p tcp --dport 25 --state 
NEW -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix "25port: "
```

... but this is not correct, because vmbr is the bridge.
How I can get traffic logs from virtual interfaces on port 25?

Comment: http://ebtables.netfilter.org/misc/ebtables-faq.html#quiz3

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the `br_netfilter` module, and then enable `iptables` for bridged traffic, by means of

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
```

See ["What's bridge-netfilter?"](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html)